# How to interogate a query to get all the images in wordpress from wp-posts?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I want to get the all of the images from wp-post, including : date, post content, title, url

this is my query :

```
SELECT p.post_parent, p.guid, p.post_title, p.post_content, p.post_date 
FROM wp_posts p 
WHERE ((p.post_mime_type = "image/jpeg" OR p.post_mime_type = "image/png"  OR p.post_mime_type = "image/gif")
AND (p.post_parent = p.id))
```

If i get removed the " `AND (p.post_parent = p.id))"` I got the all of the result, but the post assign to it . This query return me nothing. How can I get this items ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I manage it out : this is the wanted result :

```
SELECT p.post_parent, p.guid, p.post_title, wp.post_content, p.post_date 
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp
ON p.post_parent = wp.id
WHERE (p.post_mime_type = "image/jpeg" OR p.post_mime_type = "image/png"  OR p.post_mime_type = "image/gif")
```